# Escaping double quotes in a style string in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery div as follows:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 bg-image"
     style="background-image: url('images/page-1_img09.jpg')" data-equal-group="1">
</div>
```

What I would like to be able to do is create a dynamic image variable within a function and escape the quotes similar to this:

```
// some code      
      var html  = "";
      var photo = data[i].photo;
        html += "<div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-6 bg-image pull-sm-right pull-lg-left' style='background-image: url('";
        html += photo; 
        html += "')' data-equal-group='1'></div>";
```

The problem that I am having is that the double quotes around the image.jpg are not loading into the browser. Instead this is what I get:

```
background-image: url(images/demsoc.jpg)
```

Is there another way of doing this which would include the single quotes?

Comment: you mean the single quotes are not loading.

Comment: If you use `document.createElement()` instead of a tweaked string, it will be way easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format properly the quotes like:

```
var html = "<div class='classes' style=\"background-image: url('" + data[i].photo +"')\" data-equal-group='1'>test</div>";
//                                      ^---- Has to be Double-Q. so escape them ------^
```

to recap: url address *should* be in single quotes, therefore the style=`""` quotes has to be double quotes. Since you already use double quotes to delimit your JS String, those have to be escaped `style=\" blabla \"`.

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/dehuba/1/edit?html,js,console,output)***

Result from Developer Tools Elements Console:

```
<div class="classes" style="background-image: url('//placehold.it/300x300')" data-equal-group="1">test</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Worked like a charm